# Detecting & preventing proxy signups: Check port 80

Tags: php, spam-prevention

Is it ethical/legal to check port 80 one time upon registration in an automated fashion to determine if a user is a proxy or not? We've been having a large flood of user signups who then proceed to spam/troll, often with common shock sites embedded in posts or PMs.

I know that some sorts of port scans are legal, for example, Rizon, an irc network, scans some ports in compliance with a legal code.

Is it legal for me to do this with port 80 on the user's computer? No average user will have a webserver running on their computer, correct? If they do, as I do and my friend does, it'd probably be inaccessible behind their firewall or not port forwarded, right?

What other programs use port 80 that could interfere with this scan?

If it's illegal or unethical to do this, what's a better way to check if a user is a proxy?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
error_reporting(0);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$port = 80;

$timeout = 5;
$pLen = 0;
$fp = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
if(!$fp){
    die('Not a proxy');
}else{
    die('Proxy'); 
}
```

Comment: I believe slashdot did something like this, and may still.  Attempting to connect to a single port isn't really a "port scan" in the typical sense of the term.

Comment: So it's not something that I'm really at risk for being in trouble for later? Must I inform users somewhere that this is happening?

Comment: Don't ask for legal advice, nobody will give you it here. At least I would question that information. So if you really need to know ask folks you can really trust.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be legal, but I am not a lawyer, and don't assume people won't be running a web server. If you're going to check, check to see if it is an open proxy or not, not just if there is something running on port 80.

Comment: How would I be able to check if it's an open proxy?

Comment: I would recommend you find a library to do this for you. You could also look at the specification for HTTP proxies, look at an example (http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/proxycheck.html), or use a DNSBL of open proxies (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL).

Comment: Oh jeez that's overly confusing.

Comment: Can't I just check if the page has "cPanel", "glype", or "proxy" on it if the http server loads? What's the chance a legitimate user will show up with an http server on their computer which is NOT behind a firewall and is being PF'd properly, and has any of those words?